# Unit Test: Evaluate Singleton into Function

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, mocking, xcuitest

I need your help, this time for Unit Test and how to evaluate a Singleton into Function. This is my context:

I have a class, which it has a Singleton like this:

```
class ClassToTest (){
    var testMessage = ""

    init(){
        // This is only a empty init
    }

    func funcWhichHasASingleton() {
        testMessage = "Function was covered"

        MySingleton.shared.sendAnalytics("params")
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a singleton where is sending analytics

> MySingleton.shared.sendAnalytics("params")

And I have my test function like this:

```
func testExample() {
    // Given
    let sut = ClassToTest()

    // When
    sut.funcWhichHasASingleton()

    // Then
    XCTAssertEqual(sut.testMessage, "Function was covered")
}
```

The my question is: how I can test the Singleton into ClassToTest, such as Xcode pass into that function but my SonarQube says I need to cover the Singleton line. How can I do that?

Comment: It depends on the singleton. If you can, refactor your singleton so that it it has an initializer for testing so you can create more than once instance.   However, yours is sending analytics, so part of that refactoring will be to inject a dependency on something that actually does communication.  Then you can mock that.  In real execution, you use the shared static property that is initialized with the thing that does the actual communication. For testing you can create a free-standing instance into which you inject a mock that simulates communication with analytics server.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking this down a little, what you actually need to to test is not the function being called but what the function does. In this case, I think you want to make sure the analytics are being called.

In which case you would need to do something like:

```
class ClassToTest {

    let analytics: MySingleton

    init(analytics: MySingleton) {
        self.analytics = analytics
    }

    func funcWhichHasASingleton() {
        analytics.sendAnalytics("params")
    }
}
```

Then you are in a position to test the analytics, possibly with a mock.

```
func testExample() {

    let analytics = MySingleton.shared // or better, some kind of Mock class.

    // Given
    let sut = ClassToTest(analytics: analytics)

    // When
    sut.funcWhichHasASingleton()

    // Then
    XCTAssertEqual(analytics.messageCount, 1) // You would need to be able to monitor what the singletons does.
}
```

Potentially, if you can have a mock MySingleton, then you can do this. Maybe using Mockingbird or use a protocol witness.

```
let didSendSendExpectation = expectation("")

analytics.didRecieve { message in
    didSendSendExpectation.fulfill()
}

// When
sut.funcWhichHasASingleton()

wait(for: didSendSendExpectation, timeout: 0.1)
```